# Mac M1 - tensorflow-dependent package installation not working

Tags: tensorflow, pip, dependencies, apple-m1

I am using a MacBook Pro M1 and try to install the package `dmol-book`, which has `tensorflow`-dependency, via `pip3 install dmol-book==1.3.2` .

It throws the following error:

```
ERROR: Ignored the following versions that require a different python version: 1.0.1 Requires-Python >=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3,!=3.4.*,<3.9; 1.1.0 Requires-Python >=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<3.9; 1.1.1 Requires-Python >=2.7,!=3.0.*,!=3.1.*,!=3.2.*,!=3.3.*,!=3.4.*,<3.9
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow>=2.7 (from dmol-book) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow>=2.7
```

I have installed `tensorflow` via

```
pip3 install tensorflow-macos
pip3 install tensorflow-metal
```

I can use `tensorflow` within python3:

```
>>> import tensorflow
>>> tensorflow.__version__
'2.11.0'
>>> tensorflow.__file__
'/Users/username/.pyenv/versions/3.10.7/envs/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py'
```

but `pip3 list` does not list `tensorflow`, only

```
tensorboard             2.11.0
tensorboard-data-server 0.6.1
tensorboard-plugin-wit  1.8.1
tensorboardX            2.5.1
tensorflow-estimator    2.11.0
tensorflow-macos        2.11.0
tensorflow-metal        0.7.0
tensorstore             0.1.28
```

`tensorflow` also shows up as a directory in the original virtual environment directory, that I created:
`/Users/username/pathtovirtualenv/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow`

Can someone help me to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is a common problem for M1 users, that their tensorflow package is tensorflow-macos, and not the standard tensorflow package (literally just called tensorflow).

Comment: But the ```venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/``` directory does contain a package directory called ```tensorflow```, which is also the one ```python3``` imports. So my understanding is that I do have the 'normal' ```tensorflow```-package, ```pip3``` for some reason just does not list it.

Comment: No, you have a folder called tensorflow (made by the tensorflow-macos/apple) package, no package known to pip is called tensorflow. That is your actual problem and confusion.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I resolved the issue by cloning the git-repo of the ```dmol-book```, changing the dependency in the ```setup.py```-file (from ```tensorflow``` to ```tensorflow-macos```) and then installing the package via ```python3 setup.py install```.

Answer (score -1):

I think its because it does not find a version that satisfies the requirement as mentioned.

Comment: But as I showed, my ```tensorflow```-version is 2.11.0, and it requires a version >=2.7, and as you can see in the path to the ```tensorflow```-package, my ```python``` version is 3.10.7

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).